# Limit of $\left(\left(\frac{1-x}{e}\right)^{1/x}\right)^{1/\sin x} $ when $x\to0$

Tags: limits

How would I start for computing this limit:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \left( \dfrac{1-x}{e} \right) ^ { \dfrac{1}{x} } \right) ^ { \dfrac{1}{\sin x} } $$

My father asked this question. He does not know whether it actually has a real limit or not.

Comment: Just plug in very small values to get evidence if the limit exists or not

Comment: I don't think there are any computation of limits. There are proofs of the limit to be some value or undefined.

Comment: But, yes you can plug some small values for some estimation and then continuing from there for the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take the logarithm of
$$\left(\frac{1-x}e\right)^{\frac1{x\sin(x)}}$$then take the limit.

You'll get

$$\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\frac{\ln(1-x)-1}{x\sin(x)}}=0$$

because 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-x)-1}{x\sin(x)}=-\infty \tag 1$$

and because the exponential function is continuously decreasing through positive numbers towards zero as its argument is tending to $-\infty.$

$(1)$ is easy to see without using the L'Hospital rule. (Just think of $\ln(1)=0$, and of the continuity of the logarithmic function.)

Comment: Perhaps you should say that your final step is valid because $\exp$ is continuous.

Comment: @user21820: Yes, thx, indeed. I correct.

Comment: Technically you swapped limit with $\exp$ so you want continuity of $\exp$.

Comment: And the funny thing is that we so often use the affinely-extended reals as you are doing here, but it's not taught in conventional analysis courses.

Comment: @user21820: You are right again. I just sketched my solution because I got angry because of the reference to the L' rule.

Comment: Yes indeed the L'Hopital's rule cannot be applied directly because it is of the wrong form. I only just noticed it. And why on earth did my answer get 2 downvotes when it is so precise and gives more information than any other answer?!

Comment: @user21820: I don't see down votes...  : (     -- The smily of a malignant fellow.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use L'Hopital as it tells you almost nothing about the behaviour, and in fact cannot be used directly on this question as Shantty's answer attempts to, since the expression is not of a suitable indeterminate form.

As $x \to 0$:

$\left( \dfrac{1-x}{e} \right) ^ { \frac{1}{x\sin(x)} } = \exp\left( \dfrac{\ln(1-x)-1}{x\sin(x)} \right)$

$\in \exp\left( \dfrac{1}{x^2} \dfrac{-1-x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^3)}{1-\frac{1}{6}x^2+O(x^4)} \right)$ [by Taylor expansions]

$\subseteq \exp\left( \dfrac{1}{x^2} (-1-x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^3))(1+\frac{1}{6}x^2+O(x^4)) \right)$

$\subseteq \exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{2}{3}+O(x)\right)$

$\subseteq \exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{x}\right) e^{-\frac{2}{3}}(1+O(x))$

$\to 0$ [because $\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{x}\right) \to 0$].

This shows not only the limit but exactly how fast it goes to $0$.

***Comments***

The notation above is a **rigorous** Landau notation, unlike the slipshod **abuse of notation using the equals-sign**. To be precise, "$t(x) \in O(f(x))$ as $x \to 0$" is a **standard short-form** for:

> $\exists c\ \exists δ>0\ \forall x\ ( |x|<δ \Rightarrow |t(x)| < c|f(x)| )$.

Comment: The set notation here is non-standard and confusing.

Comment: @SimonS: It is standard. It is the usual **abuse** of notation with Big-O notation that is not good. Check any proper reference and they will corroborate that the Landau notation denotes classes of functions.

Comment: @SimonS: Don't forget that if you write using "$=$", it is simply **logically** wrong. Frankly you're really mean if you downvoted my answer because of that since it's the only one that provided more information about the asymptotic behaviour than the only other correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

By taking log on both sides. 
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(1-x) - 1}{x\sin x}$$
now proceed by l'Hôpital rule.

Comment: L'Hopital does not work because it is not of the required form.